# Create dll on runtime in c++

Tags: c++, dll

Im using codeblocks and c++.

The problem that i have when i work on big projects is that a lot of the code goes to creating the interface. It takes a lot of time and a lot of fixing bugs.

I want to create a program that lets me edit the c++ code from my future projects. Lets call it A. A will be able to create a interface for my project by modifying the c++ code. Now, during runtime when A creates a new project it creates its cpp file and its dll file. When A adds a button for exemple, it will change its c++ and save the result on the dll. Then When i decide my project its finished,i want to turn that dll into an exe. I did my best to explain things in few words. Hope you get the idea

I know you can create a dll manually by clicking new project,then by selecting Dynamic Link Libraby, but is it possible to create a dll during runtime? Basically like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const char* str=
    "
    ///c++ code
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        if(i%2==0)
            cout<<i;
    "

    const char* path="dllName.dll";
    f(str,path);

    return 0;
}
```

The str is a array in which i store some correct c++ code
The f function is the answer i need from you.

Im new to this topic(dll files, so if i asked something stupid and obvious i apologise)

Comment: Dll is a compiled executable file. So having some "correct c++ code" would not help you much. What exactly you are trying to achieve? Why do you need to create dynamic libraries runtime?

Comment: I modified my question by adding the explination

Answer (score 3):

A C++ program can't compile code at run time. The best you can do is ask to your program to call the compiler then the compiler will create your dll.

Answer (score 3):

You could write the contents of str to a temporary file and let your program execute a compiler using this file as input.

Answer (score 3):

Produce source code into file, then calling compiler as external process to compile the cpp file.

```
{
    ofstream f("hello.cpp");
    f << "your hello world code";
}
system("msvc.exe hello.cpp -some_dll_make_command hello.dll");
```

Comment: @robertooverflow97: Considering it's calling MSVC, I'd say it works on Windows _only_

Answer (score 0):

Check out `LoadLibrary`, `FreeLibrary`, and `GetProcAddress`. I assume what you want is dynamically load/unload dlls at runtime.